# Find Unix Timestamp of Midnight on Most Previous Monday

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

How can I find the Unix Timestamp of midnight on (the beginning of) the most previous Monday?

Comment: can the most previous monday be today (if today is monday), or would it be the monday 1 week ago?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

```
date("r", strtotime("last monday"));
```

yields

```
Mon, 28 Jun 2010 00:00:00 -0700
```

Comment: mk, i've glanced at `strtotime()` but it's one of those things that makes me go "Are you suuure?"

Comment: PHP has a lot of magic. That's why we love and hate it so much.